# Is there any reason to use redux sage with axios instead of RTK Query createApi function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, saga

I'm wondering if redux sage + axios still makes it easier to handle data fetching or redux tool kit query is advanced enough for managing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write about that in [Side Effect Approaches](https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches).

Generally: `redux-saga` will never make anything easier.
It's a tool that is known for being "powerful", but definitely not for "easy".
As the Redux team, we recommend against using `redux-saga` in almost all situations.
Our recommendation is to always go for the most simple tool required for the job at hand, and if that means going for two or three different tools in an application, in our eyes that's better than, say, using a power-drill for the three jobs of hammering a nail into the wall, screwing in a delicate screw and really making a hole into a wall.

So we usually recommend looking at tools in the following order: (see [Recommendations](https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches#recommendations))

- RTK Query for data fetching
- thunks for everything else that should be called imperatively
- listenerMiddleware for everything reactive

Only after all these tools didn't give you what you need, `redux-saga` might be an option. That is usually if you have extremely complex asynchronous logic. Most of that can still be done with the listener middleware though - the only thing I can think of that's only offered by sagas would be action channels.